# how do I use 'dict' without list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am beginner to the python, it would be great help if anybody can help to me understand why `dict`  works with list comprehension and does not work with simple parameter argument in my case ? both code sample are given below,

Input: (I am reading below data from .txt file and converting in to JSON)

```
vm4 : Windows10
vm2 : Ubuntu14
vm1 : Ubuntu14
vm3 : MacOSX10.11
```

working code.

```
file1 = dict(i.split(':') for i in file1.split('\n'))
```

Code Not working

```
for i in file1.split('\n'):
    print dict(i.split(':'))

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-048ba6a1e29b> in <module>()
      1 for i in file1.split('\n'):
----> 2     print dict(i.split(':'))

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

Comment: If your data in `.txt` file is already formatted as `dict` then use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`.

Comment: I make a copy of you `txt` and use this code and work perfect: `with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    file1 = dict(i.split(" : ") for i in file)`

Comment: @GarbageCollector That is _very_ unsafe! Don't do that!

Comment: My code  `file1 = dict(i.split(" : ") for i in file)` is working absolutely fine.!  but i dont understand why it was not working without list comprehension.! I need some explanation for this .. if any one can help over here. ! One thing I noticed that for list comprehension we are passing entire `for` loop as `dict` argument. for another piece of code we are not doing so.. that might be the reason ..!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to turn the contents of the text file into a dictionary?

If so, is this what you wanted:

```
d = {}
with open("text.txt") as f:  
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(' : ')
        d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'vm4': 'Windows10', 'vm2': 'Ubuntu14', 'vm1': 'Ubuntu14', 'vm3': 'MacOSX10.11'}
```